# Exception coming When Converting Base64String to Byte array - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64

I have very large `Base64` encode string for file size of about 50mb.I want to save this file on server, I am using below code to file on server, But I get exception :

**Exception:**

```
"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."
```

**Code:**

```
byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, filebytes);
```

I think due to large size of `Base64` string max length of byte array is exceeding, Please help me how I can fix this issue,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData.Replace(" ","+"));
```

Comment: This will not work, as in Replace function 1st param oldValue length should be greater than 0, so i would get exception

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing empty strings with '+' in fileData. This exception usually comes due to empty strings.